# JPGraph size of pie graph

Tags: jpgraph

I already had a functioning pie graph here (in terms of the data being displayed). It is a multi-pie graph showing 3 pie graphs in one graph. My problem is that I wanted to make my graph size bigger so that everything can fit the area and yet be able to see a complete view of the chart. Currently, I am using the code below (followed by the resulting screenshot):

```
$graph = new PieGraph(800,800);
```

[image: graph at 800,800]

However, when I changed it to:

```
$graph = new PieGraph(1000,1000);
```

[image: graph at 1000,1000]

hoping to make my "chart area" bigger, the pie graphs just became "zoom-out" and the "chart area" is still the same. All I wanted is that my charts will be fitted and not crowded. As you can see in the screenshot, there is not much difference. I also tried higher values and still the same.

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this link. I think this will be help you :
[Jpgraph pie plot set size](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/classref/PiePlot3D.html#_PIEPLOT3D_SETHEIGHT)

```
$pieplot->SetSize(0.5);
$pieplot->SetCenter(0.5, 0.4);
```